# Update google sheet by rowid using API

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have employee in one sheet and I get row id of the searched employee on the page now I want to update the same record with the row id so that my time of searching the employee is saved. Is there any way to do this?

```js
function getEmployeeName_(){
try{
    var username = getUserName_();
    
    var formObject = {verb:'GET',url:'/Employees?Emp_Email='+g_obj.current_user_email};
    var response_obj = processForm(formObject);
    response_obj = JSON.parse(response_obj);  
    
    var userObj = {};
    if(response_obj != undefined && response_obj.status != undefined && response_obj.status == 'success'){
      if(response_obj['data'].length >0){
        userObj = response_obj['data'][0];
       }
    }
 
    return userObj.Emp_Name;
  }catch(e){
    Logger.log(e.message);
    return { status: 'error', message: 'Something went wrong while fetching User Name.'};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To update values in Sheets API, [use spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update). The `rowId` you're talking about will be a part of range property using [A1Notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation).

To check samples on using sheets values.update, check [Sheet Operations](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet).